# Powerapps - Working with Test Studio - Issue with Selecting Rows in Data Tables

Tags: powerapps

I have an application that contains a collection, a Data Table, and a set of controls to amend the selected item in the Data Table.
The application can correctly

Respond to a mouse click on a row and column in the data table to set a context variable.
Use the contents of the context variable to fill out text edit fields
Update the context variable with the amended text edits
On clicking the Save Button, the appropriate row in the collection - and the Data Table is updated.
This can't be tested effectively in Test Studio, as when I record my actions as above, the record function in Test Studio only records
Select(Column_Name), and does not record the row which I selected as per 1. above.  Instead the Select refers to the first item displayed in the Data Table consistently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment the Select function (and Test Studio) does not work with data tables. Test Studio is still an experimental feature, I believe before it reaches the general availability stage it will be supporting all of the built-in controls.

Comment: Any idea on when this will happen?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know; I'm guessing it will be announced in the [Power Apps Blog](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/), or updated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/test-studio).